# Plotly: Align two y-axes in different scales

Tags: python, plotly

I have a line chart generated with two different databases and I would like to align the two grids of the y-axes. This is the plot generated by the code:

[image]

I would like a single y-axis for the ticks, instead of multiples:

```
fig = go.Figure()

fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['Date'], y=df['Adj Close'], line_color='#222f3e', name='Coinbase', yaxis = 'y1'), secondary_y=True)
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df2['Date'], y=df2['Adj Close'], line_color='#FFC312', name='Bitcoin', yaxis = 'y2'), secondary_y=False)

fig.update_layout(
    title={'text':'Performance comparada: Bitcoin e Coinbase','x':0.5},
    xaxis_title='',
    yaxis_title='',
    paper_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    font=dict(family="Montserrat SemiBold"))

fig.update_xaxes(showgrid=True,
                 gridwidth=0.005, 
                 gridcolor='#dfe6e9')

fig.update_yaxes(showgrid=True,
                 gridwidth=0.005, 
                 gridcolor='#dfe6e9',
                 tickprefix='$',
                 showtickprefix='all')

fig.update_yaxes(title_text='', secondary_y=True)
fig.update_xaxes(showline=True, linewidth=2, linecolor='black')
fig.update_yaxes(showline=True, linewidth=2, linecolor='#FFC312', secondary_y=True)
fig.update_yaxes(showline=True, linewidth=2, linecolor='#222f3e', secondary_y=False)

fig.update_layout(yaxis2=dict(anchor="x2", overlaying='y1', side='right'))
                  
fig.show()
```

Comment: I am a bit confused – why are you using `fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])` if you don't want a secondary y axis? this also overwrites your original line `fig = go.Figure()`

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to align the grids, so either set the numbers manually or hide the second grid. `fig.update_layout(yaxis2=dict(tickvals=[127.5,140.5,154.0,167.5,180.5]))` OR `fig.update_layout(yaxis2=dict(showgrid=False))`